# handling bigdata from excel in php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, laravel, phpexcel

This is an opinion based question. 
Let I have a excel file with 4k row and 50 column.
I have to handle this file in step by step. Here I mention the steps

1. validate every field of every row. (here some mysql query run for checking database related validation)
2. if all data is valid then I have to save this data in 3 table and update 1 table 
   **example**
   column `1-20` insert in `table_1`
   column `21-40` insert in `table_2`
   column `41-50` insert in `table_3`
   update `table_1` with last `insert id` of `table_2` and `table_3`

Now I want to know that what is the best practice to handle this big data.
any suggestion compatible `php`, `cakephp` or `laravel`

Comment: It's a pretty vague question. Are you having any specific problem?

Comment: actually I don't test this big data. I have test with 10-15 row of data. I ask this question for knowing the best practice to do that type of job

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to know that what is the best practice to handle this big data.

As you handle any other "big data" as well: Read and process it in chunks of a given size so each chunk fits into the limitations of the system.